# In ZFC, is the Axiom of Power Sets implied by the principle of restricted comprehension?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Can we consider an instance of the principle of restricted comprehension in which the property of the elements of a given set A is that of being a subset of a set B? (i.e. A is P(B))

Comment: What is the Axiom of Parts?

Comment: Sorry, I've changed the question. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

No, the axiom of restricted comprehension can only choose some of the elements of a set, so the resulting set has no more elements than the one you started with.  If we start with $\{a,b\}$ we can get any one subset of it but we can't get them all and collect them together into one set.  The outcome of Power set is $\{\emptyset, \{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\},$ which has four elements.  We can't get that with restricted comprehension or replacement.